# Fastest way to write the following

Tags: python, performance, numpy, optimization, vectorization

I'm doing the following in python:

```
tmp = np.empty_like(J,dtype=X.dtype)
for idx, (ii, jj) in enumerate(zip(I, J)):
    tmp[idx] = sum((X[ii] - X[jj])**2)
```

where X is a 50000 x 128 numpy array
and I and J are integer numpy arrays of size (763690,) (columns and rows of a sparse matrix)

Now the problem is that the above operation takes about 30 seconds to complete, and I don't see what I need to do to speed this up. I know it can be done faster, since I have a similar code in Matlab where it barely takes any time.

What am I doing wrong here?
Is it something about memory stride access?, not using builtin functions? or something else? should I parallelize/vectorize it?

(I know the title is terrible, but I couldn't figure out a good way to write it, suggestions are welcome!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with:

```
np.sum((X[I]-X[J])**2, axis=1)
```

Here we thus first use subscripting to generate a *763 690×128* matrix `X[I]` where for each item in `I` we use the corresponding row in `X`. The same happens for `X[j]`. We then subtract the two, and obtain a *763 690×128* matrix. We can element-wise square the items, and then calculate the sum over the first axis. This thus means that fore every row, we obtain a single value. The result is thus a *flat* array with *763 690* elements.

Answer (score 1):

Willems method worked wonderful!

```
np.sum((X[I]-X[J])**2, axis=1)
```

it took the operation time from ~30s to ~0.6s, thank you very much :)